# how multiple image links are stored in the mysql database

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I am developing an e-commerce website where for each seller there are multiple images for each item. Can any one give me some suggestions on what is the best way/structure to handle the storage of these image links.

Currently I already have some solutions but not sure if they are efficient enough.
1. create another mysql table to associate items and images (I really don't like this solution)

2. use some special char to delimit image links
3. store a JSON string containing an array of image links. When I need those links, read the JSON string into an object and do the work.

I'm not good at analyzing I/O. Could any one give me some suggestions and directions?

Comment: If you're worried about the cost of joins in solution 1 (which is the solution textbooks advise), you can use indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you don't like solution 1? It's the best and simple solution to your problem.

Option #2 and #3 requires you to read the database field and use some function to read/parse field to get URLs. Inserts or updates to this multivalued fields can be a nightmare and error prone.

Option #1 requires other table with PK/FK relationship, but is the more manageable solution.

Just use your solution #1.